# VSCode peek variable declaration for unsupported languages

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible in VSCode to peek the declaration (or first mention) of a certain variable in unsupported languages?

I work a lot with Matlab, and in long scripts it would be helpful if I could have a little peek window (as in e.g. C, Python) to see the first definition of the variable. Of course this variable could have been changed in the script (and without proper symbols there is probably not really a way to detect this), but let's assume that it isn't.

To illustrate what I mean with a Python example:

[image]

Comment: I'm no Matlab expert at all, but there is a [Matlab extension for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gimly81.matlab). Does that not provide the feature you need?

Comment: @DominikSchreiber I am using that extension, but unfortunately that does not provide that feature. I see that there are some other extensions in the marked that allow this for CSS or vue.